# How to change WPR trace files names?

Tags: windows, trace, xperf, wpr

I am new to Windows Performance Recorder (WPR) and want to know if there is a way to change the names of the trace files when I run a RebootCycle.

The command I am using right now is:

> wpr -start GeneralProfile -filemode -onoffscenario RebootCycle -onoffresultspath C:\traces -numiterations 1

With the above command, WPR generates boot and shutdown trace files with the filename in a format something like:

> ***Machine-Name.Date.Time.RebootCycle_1.Boot.etl***.

This causes the trace files to have a different name each time I run my command, but I want to have pre-defined names like ***boot.etl*** and ***shutdown.etl***. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this Microsoft an got a reply today. Currently (Windows 10 TH2 version of WPR) It is not supported to change the file name, only the path. They **may** add it in newer WPR version.